# Ruby/Rails - consume webservice with ActiveResource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, web-services, rest, activerecord, activeresource

just getting started with Rails, I would like to consume a webservice (using ActiveResource) that has the following endpoint:

**GET /user?some_header=XYZ**

This is my ActiveResource Class:

```
    class User < ActiveResource::Base
      self.site = "url"
      set_collection_name 'user'  #avoid pluralization within the url
    end
```

How would a call for the above endpoint now look like?

I tried

```
    User.get('', headers={:some_header => "XYZ"})
```

but I'm getting a 404 (the request works when I fire it by hand).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
User.all(:params=>{:some_header => "XYZ"})
```

If you want to avoid format in your path, you can ovveride base collection_path method

```
   def collection_path(prefix_options = {}, query_options = nil)
        prefix_options, query_options = split_options(prefix_options) if query_options.nil?
        "#{prefix(prefix_options)}#{collection_name}.#{format.extension}#{query_string(query_options)}"
    end
```

to

```
   def collection_path(prefix_options = {}, query_options = nil)
        prefix_options, query_options = split_options(prefix_options) if query_options.nil?
        "#{prefix(prefix_options)}#{collection_name}#{query_string(query_options)}"
      end
```

Comment: Tried it, getting an strange error **undefined method `collect!' for #<Hash:0x48bbe30>**
. When I look at the log file it seems that the right request is constructed though.

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem. Although I specified an empty path in my get method, Rails internally appended ".json", so the constructed URL was

/user/.json?some_header=XYZ"

The way I fixed it was

```
     User.collection_name = ""
     User.get('user', headers={:some_header => "XYZ"})
```

Anyone knows a cleaner solution?